# gappa seems to generate bad Coq

Tags: coq, gappa

I'm using the -Bcoq backend of gappa.
The coq file contains dollar signs.
So far as I can tell, a coq file should not contain dollar signs.
Here is a snippet from -Bcoq :

```
Lemma t4 : p22 -> p21.  
 intros h0.  
 refine (nzr_of_abs _manb i1 h0 _) ; finalize.  
Qed.  
Lemma l23 : s1 -> p21 (* NZR(manb) *).  
 intros h0.  
 assert (h1 := l24 h0).  
 apply t4. exact h1.  
Qed.  
Lemma t5 : p1 -> p19 -> p20 -> p21 -> p18.  
 intros h0 h1 h2 h3.  
 refine (b33 i1 h0 i7 h1 i8 h2 h3 $) ; finalize.  
Qed.
```

The compiler, coqc, chokes on the dollar signs.
If I change all the dollar signs to underbars,
coqc is happy with the change and
coqchk is happy with the output of coqc.

I'm having the problem with more than one version of gappa:

```
$ gappa --version
Gappa 1.3.5
$ gappa141 --version
Gappa 1.4.1
$ coqc --version
The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.13.2 (October 2022)
compiled on Oct 6 2022 0:00:00 with OCaml 4.12.0
```

I compiled gappa141 myself, with help from gcc.
gappa and coqc are from a fedora repository.

Should I be getting a more recent version of coq that likes dollar signs?
Is this a bug in gappa?

Apparently tags for gappa are not allowed.
This is the only forum for provers that I have found.
If someone knows of a better forum for my questions,
that would be useful knowledge.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, [what gappa is](https://gappa.gitlabpages.inria.fr/gappa/index.html): Gappa (Génération Automatique de Preuves de Propriétés Arithmétiques — automatic proof generation of arithmetic properties) is a tool intended to help verifying and formally proving properties on numerical programs and circuits handling floating-point or fixed-point arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to install gappa via [Coq Platform](https://github.com/coq/platform) - either using an installer or the scripts? Gappa is included in the "full" level of Coq Platform. There is btw. also a Coq plugin for gappa, which automatically translates Coq goals to gappa, but it is a bit more restricted than using gappa directly. Coq Platform also allows to install older versions of Coq (including 8.13.2) and these also contain gappa.

I am using gappa myself and the Coq Platform supplied versions seems to be fine.

Comment: Does that mean I'd have to scrap the system I have?  Do your coq files have dollar signs?

Comment: Coq Platform is designed such that you can have many variants installed on one system. If you use an installer, you can install to a different folder. If you use the scripts, Coq Platform will create a unique opam switch - your existing opam switches won't be touched (except in the unlikely case that you use a Coq Platform standard switch name).

Comment: I'm trying to install from the coq platform, but not faring too well.  I downloaded platform-8.13.1 , thinking I would get coq 8.13.2 and gappa.  Do not remember where I got it.  Apparently 'tain't a full edition.  Installed stuff.  Checked the coqc version.  Tried to check the gappa version.  Oops: no gappa.  In this case, I want to start over, but I do not know how.  I want to start over because I noticed that the full version would come with gamma 1.4.0, which was a non-working version: it choked on unary minus.  The bug report was mine.  I think I've since worn out my welcome with author.

Comment: I Still do not have platform gappa.  Since I already had a .v file, thought I'd try with what I had.  No go: $ coqc refine1_wtf_coq.v File "./refine1_wtf_coq.v", line 1, characters 15-34: Error: Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path matching suffix Gappa.  Also cannot figure out how to put a line break in a comment.  Found https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting , but it does not help.  No longer know how I did it in the original question.

Comment: Finally got gappa.  Contrary to expectation, 1.4.1 . opam install gappa   This gappa did not put in dollar signs.  Do not know why mine did.  coqc still will not compile result:   coqc refine1_10_03.v  File "./refine1_10_03.v", line 1, characters 15-34:Error: Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path matching suffix Gappa.  Require Import Gappa.Gappa_library.

Comment: @MichaelHennebry: sorry but your posts don't contain enough information to help you. E.g. it would be interesting to know if you install Coq Platfor, via a binary installer or compiling from sources using the scripts. If you use the scripts, please always use the latest ones, they also support installing old versions. If you used an installer, the likely cause is that you did set environment variables in some way to confuse coq (say set COQLIB and PATH in a not matching way, best is to set only PATH and not COQLIB).

Comment: I think such individual support questions are better handled in the Coq Zulip chat - they are usually not very helpful for others.

Comment: Ok. I'll try that after I've reinstalled my OS. I cannot figure out how else to back out of what I've already done.  This is the first prover forum I managed to find.  Not obvious that Zulip is right either, but if not, maybe I can get directions to one that is.

Comment: If you would tell what you have done, there is likely a better way to fix things than reinstalling the OS. As I said, I think this is better discussed in the Coq Zulip chat: (https://coq.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/250632-Coq-Platform.20devs.20.26.20users)